# Pass Youtube Video Id Through Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube-api

Consider that I have an object, with a YouTube videoId as one of the parameters, in a list view.  I know how to use the OnItemClickListener and how to pass an extra through an intent.  When I get to the receiving Activity I have to call intent.getStringExtra("key") in the onCreate method.  I need that retrieved videoId in another method, onInitializationSuccess, for when I call the cueVideo(videoId) method.  Can you explain not only what to do but why so I can understand for my own growth.

```
public class PlayVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity
    implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{


private String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCKcPfcvaFtN_izxXg7lzEcKVdF0A-7y1Q";
String VIDEO_ID = "ZHAe-SaplCw";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);

    YouTubePlayerView playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    playerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, this);

    //Get videoId from current ListView Object
    Intent getVideoId = getIntent();
    String videoId = getVideoId.getStringExtra("videoIdExtra");

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    if(!wasRestored){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }
}

private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int i) {

    }
};

YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Play Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

Comment: You already have `getVideoId.getStringExtra`, so what's the question?

Comment: I had a brain fart, I just realized I can make a global variable, initialize it in the onCreate method and then call it in the onInitializationSuccess method. But that's what my problem was.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to accept my answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either declare a member variable, or just call `getIntent` in that other method and get the ID there.

> Can you explain [...] why

Because you want to use the value outside of onCreate

Answer (score 0):

What I have been using and its working fine.

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
private MyPlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener;
private YouTubePlayer player;
private String videoKey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
    playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    videoKey = bundle.getString(Constants.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_KEY, null);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player = player;
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(videoKey) ? "fhWaJi1Hsfo" : videoKey);
        // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
    }


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return youTubeView;
}

private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.

    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
        // Called when buffering starts or ends.
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int i) {
        // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
        // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
    }
}

private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        // Called when the player is loading a video
        // At this point, it's not ready to accept commands affecting playback such as play() or pause()
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {
        // Called when a video is done loading.
        // Playback methods such as play(), pause() or seekToMillis(int) may be called after this callback.
        player.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        // Called when playback of an advertisement starts.
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        // Called when playback of the video starts.
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        // Called when the video reaches its end.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
        // Called when an error occurs.
    }
}
}
```

To call this

`Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_KEY, youtubeKey);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);`

also in Constants.java file

`public static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_KEY = "you_tube_video_key";`
`public static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";`
hope this helps you out